# Android Load Your String Resources Programmatically

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, android-studio

How do I Load Your String Resources Programmatically from a Class file and not an Activity:

this is in my Strings.xml

```
    <!-- FactBook Resource -->
    <string-array name="facts">
        <item>facts 1</item>
        <item>facts 2</item>
...
    </string-array>
```

Here my Class File

```
public class FactBook {

    public String[] mFacts;

    mFacts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facts);

    public String getFact() {

        String fact = "";

        // Randomly select a fact
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();  
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFacts.length);

        fact = mFacts[randomNumber];

        return fact;
    }
}
```

I get a erro. - Invalid Method declaration, return type required.

Comment: `Load Your String Resources Pro-grammatically from a Class file` get call `getResources()` you should need valid current component `Context`. so use `FactBook` class constructor for getting context during object creation and then access String array as `context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facts)`

Comment: You can't access `getResources()` from outside. If you want then only using a `Context`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `Constructor` and pass `Context` as first argument.

```
public class FactBook {

public String[] mFacts;

Context context;

public FactBook(Context con){
context=con;
mFacts =con.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facts);
}

public String getFact() {

    String fact = "";

    // Randomly select a fact
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();  
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mFacts.length);

    fact = mFacts[randomNumber];

    return fact;
 }
}
```

Now, you called this `Facebook` class like

```
FactBook fb=new Facebook(your_Activity.this);
String str=fb.getFact();
```